# Proving that the Euclidean metric results from iterating a metric on $X \times Y$.

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-explanation

Given metric spaces $X$ and $Y$, we define a metric $\rho$ on $X \times Y$ by
$$
\rho((x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)) = (\rho_X (x_1, x_2)^2 + \rho_Y (y_1, y_2)^2)^{1/2}.
$$
I'm trying to solve the below exercise.

> Show that $\rho$ defined in this way is indeed a metric, and show that the Euclidean metric is a particular case of this constructed applied iteratively to $\mathbb{R}$.

I was able to show that $\rho$ is a metric, but I can't figure out how to show that this metric gives the Euclidean metric when applied iteratively to $\mathbb{R}$. I tried proceeding by induction, which I believe requires "abusing notation" and identifying, say, $\mathbb{R}^k \times \mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$. But I wasn't able to make progress with this method.

I would appreciate some direction/hints on how to proceed. I'll update this with attempts as I work on it further.

> Here is my updated attempt. If $X = Y = \mathbb{R}$, where $X$ and $Y$ are endowed with the Euclidean metric, $|\cdot|$, we have
> $$
> \rho((x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)) = (\rho_X (x_1, x_2)^2 + \rho_Y (y_1, y_2)^2)^{1/2} = (|x_1 - x_2|^2 + |y_1 - y_2|^2)^{1/2},
> $$
> which is the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Now, suppose inductively that for some $k \geq 2$, when we allow $X = \mathbb{R}^{k-1}$ and $Y = \mathbb{R}$, this construction yields the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^k$. Now, we consider $X = \mathbb{R}^k$ and $Y =\mathbb{R}$, endow $X$ with the aforementioned metric and $\mathbb{R}$ with its standard metric, and take $y_1, y_2 \in Y$ and $\vec{x}_1$ and $\vec{x}_2$, the components of which we will call $x_i^1$ and $x_j^2$, respectively. We then consider the corresponding metric on $\mathbb{R}^k \times \mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}^{k+1}$:
> \begin{align*} 
> \rho((\vec{x}_1, y_1), (\vec{x}_2, y_2)) & = \left(\rho_X (\vec{x}_1, \vec{x}_2)^2 + \rho_Y (y_1, y_1)^2 \right)^{1/2} \\
> & = \left[\left(\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^k (x_i^1 - x_i^2)^2 \right)^{1/2} \right)^2 + |y_1 - y_2| \right]^{1/2} \\
> & = \left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^k (x_i^1 - x_i^2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2 \right]^{1/2}
> \end{align*}
> which is the Euclidean distance in $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$, with $y_1$ appended to $\vec{x}_1$ and $y_2$ appended to $\vec{x}_2$.

Comment: I guess it helps if you write down how the euclidean metric is defined. Then you might see how to do it. Start first with $\mathbb{R}^2$ and then try to generalize.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I'm able to see how letting $X = Y = \mathbb{R}$ yields the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$, but I'm not sure how to generalize from there.

Comment: Then what about $\mathbb{R}^3$? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm not sure how to generalize to $\mathbb{R}^3$. Do I let $X = Y = \mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: You want $\mathbb{R}^3=X\times Y$. If you pick $X=Y=\mathbb{R}^3$, then you get $$X\times Y=\mathbb{R}^3\times \mathbb{R}^3=\mathbb{R}^6 \neq \mathbb{R}^3.$$

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Does it matter if I let $X$ or $Y$ equal $\mathbb{R}^2$, in that case?

Comment: Well, you tell me :) what do you think?

Comment: I this there is some missing square on the RHS

Comment: @Didier Thanks, you're correct. I fixed it.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I believe it doesn't matter, but it's more natural to let $X = \mathbb{R}^k$. I posted an updated attempt. How does this look? I'm still very unsure on this.